# Proving the existance of a one- or two dimensional subspace that is both A and B invariant.

Tags: matrices, invariance

I've just started learning about invariant subspaces and I came across this exercise:

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional space over the field $\mathbb{C}$. Prove that if endomorphism matrices $A$ and $B$ satisfy the equation $A^2=B^2=I$, there exists a one- or two-dimensional subspace that is both $A$ and $B$ invariant.

The only thing that I've proven thus far is that the only possible eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ may be $1$ or $-1$ (If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ then $Av=\lambda v \Rightarrow  Iv=A^2v=\lambda Av=\lambda^{2}v$ ; this can only happen if $\lambda =\pm 1$).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you need to use that an invariant subspace allows a lot more than just eigenvectors (i.e. as soon as you find an honest eigenvector $v$ for $A $ you can pimp that one into an invariant subspace (since then $\langle v,Bv\rangle$ is an invariant subspace))

Comment: Note that the claim is false if $\dim V=0$, exclude this case.

Let $U_+$, $U_-$ be the eigen spaces of $A$ and $W_+$, $W_-$ the eigen spaces of $B$. If any of the four spaces ($U_+$, say) is trivial, then then the eigen spaces of the other matrix (i.e., $W_\pm$) are invariant.

So all four eigen spaces have positive dimension.. $u\in U_+$ can be written as $u=w_++w_-$ with $w_\pm\in W_\pm$,the $w_\pm$ depend linearly on $u$. We obtain linear maps $U_+\to W_\pm$, similarly $U_-\to W_\pm$, and ll $W$-to$U$. The kernel of any of these is nvariant, hence all 4 eigen spaces are isomorphic